# IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply isn't called on EndpointNotFoundException

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm trying to log the start and end of every WCF operation made **client-side**. For that purpose, I'm using `IClientMessageInspector`, with its `BeforeSendRequest` and `AfterReceiveReply` methods.

That works fine most of the time. However, when there isn't any message from the server (in case of `EndpointNotFoundException`, `ServerTooBusyException`, `TimeoutException`, etc.), `BeforeSendRequest` **is not called**. That is bad because the "end" event is important for my logging.

Here is a minimum repro. Run the following code **without** having any server listening on "http://localhost/testservice".

```cs
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;

[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Ping();
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            var factory = new ChannelFactory<ITestService>(
                new BasicHttpBinding(),
                new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/testservice"));
            factory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new LoggingEndpointBehavior());
            var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
            channel.Ping();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.GetType().Name);
        }
    }
}

public sealed class LoggingEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters) { }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new LoggingInspector());
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher) { }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) { }
}

public sealed class LoggingInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BeforeSendRequest");
        return null;
    }

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AfterReceiveReply");
    }
}
```

csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Desired output:

```
BeforeSendRequest
AfterReceiveReply
EndpointNotFoundException
```

Actual output:

```
BeforeSendRequest
EndpointNotFoundException
```

### Question

Is there an extension point in WCF that I can use to log the start and end of every WCF operation made client-side (guaranteed)?

I know I can just add `try`-`catch` around the `channel` calls, but it would be good if there was a extension point inside WCF itself. That way, I can pass the `channel` to other code and they don't need to worry about logging.

### More details, if you are interested

In my real code, I'm not just logging to Console, of course. I'm actually using `System.Diagnostics.Activity.Start()` and `.Stop()`.

Comment: First you need to understand the IClientMessageInspector interface to inspect client messages.

Comment: [IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply(Message, Object) method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.afterreceivereply?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) Allows the reply message to be inspected or modified after it has been received but before it is passed back to the client application. So it won't be called when the server doesn't have any messages.

Comment: Maybe you can [use Close and Abort to release WCF client resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/use-close-abort-release-wcf-client-resources).